# NSXML Parser parsing node by node

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsxml

I have an XML like this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<user id="1" name=""><class id="1" name=""><subjects id="1" name=""><books id="1" name="">   
<chapters id="1" name="">
<pages id="0" name="" url="http://172.16.33.25/casa/admin/uploads/mathematic/Page001.html"/>
<pages id="1" name="" url="http://172.16.33.25/casa/admin/uploads/mathematic/Page002.html"/>
</chapters></books></subjects></class></user>
```

Here i need the url values in array, i'm using `NSXML` Parser. How can i parse this.?

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{         
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"pages"])
    {
        NSString *urlValue=[attributeDict valueForKey:@"url"];
        [arr addObject:urlValue];
    }
}
```